# How to allow only numbers in textbox and format as US mobile number format in react js? ex : (224) - 5623 -2365

Tags: reactjs, validation, material-ui

I am using React for mobile number validation. The TextField should allow only digits and it will format as US mobile number format. I am restricting to allow only digits, but the format is not happening. I am using material-ui for validation. Below my code.

```
import React from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

export default class myClass extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            value: '',
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }
    handleChange(e) {
        const re = /[0-9]+/g;
        if (e.target.value === '' || re.test(e.target.value)) {
            this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <TextField
                    floatingLabelText="mobileNumber"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    value={this.state.value}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You can always rely on a third party library, as suggested in materialUi documentation. Check: https://material-ui.com/demos/text-fields/#formatted-inputs and https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/tree/master/react#readme

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have restricted the textbox to allow only numbers and formatted the mobile number as US mobile number format. Follow the below code.

```
handleChange(e) {
    const onlyNums = e.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    if (onlyNums.length < 10) {
        this.setState({ value: onlyNums });
    } else if (onlyNums.length === 10) {
        const number = onlyNums.replace(
            /(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/,
            '($1) $2-$3'
        );
        this.setState({ value: number });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18):

```
import Input from '@material-ui/core/Input';
```

Use `<Input type="number" />` instead.

Answer (score 9):

Its really simple in MUI
just add the line

```
<TextField
type='number' //ad this line
onChange={(e) => setCode(e.target.value)} label="Enter otp" />
```

Along with that, you can allow numbers only in any textfield. Use like this:-

```
<UR_TEXT_INPUT_COMPONENT
value={code}
onChange={(e) => setCode(parseInt(e.target.value)} label="Enter otp" />
```

Answer (score 5):

In case you are using a form-validation library like [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/), you can validate
your Textfield like this,

```
<TextField
     type="number"
     {...register("phonenum",{
         required: {
             value: true,
             message: 'Please fill this field',
         },
         pattern: {
             value: /^[1-9]\d*(\d+)?$/i,
             message: 'Please enter an integer',
         },
         min: {
             value: 1,
             message: 'Value should be atleast 1',
         },
   })}
   error={errors?.index ? true : false}
   helperText={errors?.index?.message}
/>
```

In case, you want to input phone numbers only, I would highly recommend to consider using [react-phone-input-2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-phone-input-2).

Comment: Keep in mind this method of validation has been changed for react-hook-form, in the new version

Answer (score 0):

mui.com's [Integration with 3rd party input libraries](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/#integration-with-3rd-party-input-libraries) page has telephone input [demo](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.8.4/docs/data/material/components/text-fields/FormattedInputs.tsx) code using [react-imask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-imask).

Answer (score 0):

using **type** attribute we have to pass value **ex. number**. To accept value from input

```
const CustomTextField = ({
    label,
    value,
    maxLength,
    required,
    disabled,
    handleChange,
    handleClear,
    error,
    helpertext,
    shrink,
    type,
    placeholder
}) => {
    return (
        <TextField
            label={label}
            fullWidth
            size='small'
            variant='standard'
            value={value}
            type={type} // we have to pass here type ex. number
            placeholder={placeholder}
            inputProps={{ maxLength: (maxLength && parseInt(maxLength)) || 99}}
            InputLabelProps={{ shrink: shrink, style: { fontSize: 18 } }}
            required={required}
            onChange={handleChange}
            InputProps={{
                endAdornment: (
                    (value.length > 0 && !disabled) ? <IconButton onClick={handleClear}>
                        <ClearOutlinedIcon/>
                    </IconButton> : ''
                ),
                readOnly: disabled
            }}
            error={error}
            helperText={helpertext}
        />
    )
}

CustomTextField.propTypes = {
    disabled: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    error: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    handleChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    handleClear: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    helpertext: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    maxLength: PropTypes.string,
    placeholder: PropTypes.string,
    required: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    type: PropTypes.string,
    value: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
}
```

Answer (score -5):

Set class on your Textfield:

```
<TextField type="number"
    inputProps={{className:'digitsOnly'}}
    floatingLabelText="mobileNumber"
    value={this.state.value}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    id={"mobileNumber"} name={"mobileNumber"}
/>
```

You can apply a class on your Textfield that enables only numbers as follows:

```
$(".digitsOnly").on('keypress',function (event) {
    var keynum
    if(window.event) {// IE8 and earlier
       keynum = event.keyCode;
    } else if(event.which) { // IE9/Firefox/Chrome/Opera/Safari
       keynum = event.which;
    } else {
       keynum = 0;
    }

    if(keynum === 8 || keynum === 0 || keynum === 9) {
       return;
    }
    if(keynum < 46 || keynum > 57 || keynum === 47) {
       event.preventDefault();
    } // prevent all special characters except decimal point
}
```

Restrict paste and drag-drop on your Textfield:

```
$(".digitsOnly").on('paste drop',function (event) {
    let temp=''
    if(event.type==='drop') {
        temp =$("#mobileNumber").val()+event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('text');
        var regex = new RegExp(/(^100(\.0{1,2})?$)|(^([1-9]([0-9])?|0)(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$)/g); //Allows only digits to be drag and dropped
        if (!regex.test(temp)) {
           event.preventDefault();
           return false;
        }
    } else if(event.type==='paste') {
        temp=$("#mobileNumber").val()+event.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('Text')
        var regex = new RegExp(/(^100(\.0{1,2})?$)|(^([1-9]([0-9])?|0)(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$)/g); //Allows only digits to be pasted
        if (!regex.test(temp)) {
           event.preventDefault();
           return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Call these events in componentDidMount() to apply the class as soon as the page loads.